# al consultar la en la base de datos me arroja una valor null

Tags: php

me devuelve un valor null al hacer  una consulta en la base de datos

este es la vista  para ingresar los datos y hacer la consulta

```php
<h1>ingreso</h1>
<form method="post" >

    <input type="text"  placeholder="usuario" name="usuarioIngreso" required>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Contrasena" name="passwordIngreso" required>
    <input type="submit" name="Enviar">


</form>
<?php 
$ingreso=new MvcController();
$ingreso->ingresoUsuarioController();

 ?>
```

aqui envio por el metedo Post  para consultar en la base de datos

```php
public function ingresoUsuarioController(){
    if (isset($_POST["usuarioIngreso"])) {
        # code...

        $datosController = array("usuario" 
        =>$_POST["usuarioIngreso"],"password"=>$_POST["passwordIngreso"]);

        $respuesta = Datos::ingresoUsurioModel($datosController,"usuarios");

        var_dump($respuesta);
  }
}
```

consulto en la base de datos con un select

```php
public function ingresoUsurioModel($datosModel,$tabla)
        {
            # code...


            $stmt= Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT  usuario, password,  FROM $tabla WHERE usuario=:usuario");

            $stmt->bindParam(":usuario",$datosModel["usuario"],PDO::PARAM_STR);


            $stmt->execute();


    }
```

no me consulta nada

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. ¿Podrías por favor explicar cuál es el problema? No puedes darlo por el explicado en el título de la pregunta, por favor pulsa en [edit] y explica la situación. Gracias.

Comment: primero no retornas nada asi que es `null` lo que se le asigna a la variable `$respuesta` y necesitas hacer un `get_result` o un `store_result` ya que hay solo ejecutas la query pero no obtienes los datos te recomiendo leer el manul de [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: intente  agregarle un return $stmt-> fetch ();  y me da el mismo valor null